# Sliding window with roi c++

Tags: c++, indexing

I have little indexing problem with the following for loop. Simply I am scanning the image with roi but I am not able to scan whole image. I have some non scanned regions left in the last rows and cols. Any suggestion?
Sorry for simple question.

`

```
// Sliding Window for scaning the image
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex <= lBPIIImage2.rows - roih; rowIndex = getNextIndex(rowIndex, lBPIIImage2.rows, roih, steprow))

{
    for (int colindex = 0; colindex <=lBPIIImage2.cols - roiw; colindex = getNextIndex(colindex, lBPIIImage2.cols, roiw, stepcol))

    {
        searchRect = cvRect(colindex, rowIndex, roiw, roih);
        frameSearchRect = lBPIIImage2(searchRect);
        LoopDummy = frameSearchRect.clone();
        rectangle(frame, searchRect, CV_RGB(255, 0, 0), 1, 8, 0);
        //normalize(LoopDummy, LoopDummy, 0, 255, NORM_MINMAX, CV_8UC1);
        //imshow("Track", LoopDummy);
        //waitKey(30);
        images.push_back(LoopDummy);
        Coordinate.push_back(make_pair(rowIndex, colindex));
    }

}
```

Comment: Why are there both `roiw` and `StepRow`, what is the difference between them?

Comment: I am sliding with overlapping windows thats why ı have step row. it is roiw/.5

Comment: OK, so would you like the last `cvRect` in a row also to have `roiw` width, but `rowIndex % StepRow` to be != 0, or would you like `rowIndex % StepRow` to be 0, but `cvRect` width to be less than `roiw`?

Comment: Also, not sure, but possible bug. If in the last loop iteration `rowIndex == frameWidth - roiw` then what is the last cell in a row in `cvRect` matrix? Maybe loop condition should be `<` instead of `<=`.

Comment: Yes excatlly, the last cvRect in a row has to have roiw width, so that scaning roi can scan all possible regions.

Comment: Let's assume `StepRow=5, roiw=10, frameWidth=17`. Would it be OK that there are 3 steps with `rowIndex` taking these values: 0, 5, 7? Or can we skip the mid step (5), since 0 and 7 still overlap by little? Instead of 0,5,7 do you prefer 0,5,10, but with last `cvRect` having for instance zeros padded in the end of the row?

Comment: we dont need to skip mid step.  When we go 0 5 7 its ok we are takin care of the uncovered pixels. But in my immplemattin since I am not going through framewidth 15 to 20 ı cannot cover the region 7-17

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of this

```
for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex <= frameWidth - roiw; rowindex += StepRow)
```

try something like this

```
for (int rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < frameWidth - roiw;
    rowIndex = getNextIndex(rowIndex, frameWidth, roiw, StepRow))
```

where function `getNextIndex` is like this:

```
int getNextIndex(int currentIndex, int frameSize, int roi, int step)
{
    int temp = min(currentIndex + step, frameSize - roi - 1);
    return currentIndex != temp ? temp : frameSize;
}
```

Note that I replaced `<=` with `<` in the condition part of the loop. It makes sense to me to change that bit. In my comments index values should be 0,5,6, instead of 0,5,7. If it really should stand `<=` then just remove the `- 1` part above.

Comment: Much much better, thank you very much. Im lossing very little uncovered pixels which can be neglected.

Comment: I believe the `<=` should remain in the condition and the `- 1` be dropped - if the last region is aligned with the image end, it would span the `[(frameSize - roiw), (frameSize - 1)]` interval, which covers exactly `roiw` integers. For off-by-one mistakes, my trick is to try a corner case. If `frameWidth` is equal to `roiw`, in which case you have exactly 1 scan, with the present condition you won't enter the loop at all.

Comment: I bump into an issue today when step size is very low, I mean one pixel in each coordinates, Code scans extra regions. Generally middle sections of the image.

Comment: Also, when step size is again very small it crashes. Any suggestions ?

Comment: @Hertzial_97 sorry, to be able to help you I need more detailed info about the problem that you now have.

Comment: @Dialecticus Here is the situation: Whwn ever I want to scan my imag with step size of one pixel in each dimension, How ever when ever I try this step size I am not able get out from scanning loop I updated the code above.

Comment: @Dialecticus ok I fund that the problem is not related with the sliding window but the push back to the vectors. Since I have too much info to store it gives me error. Do you have any suggestion for it ?

Comment: @Hertzial_97 use step bigger than one pixel?

Comment: @Dialecticus yes of course ı will use bigger steps ın real life I was just trying to understand why :) Andd I found it. TY for your help and time.

Answer (score 0):

[Dialecticus](https://stackoverflow.com/users/395718/dialecticus) has  your [problem covered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568240/sliding-window-with-roi-c#comment60736678_36568240), but I'd like to expand a little. The problem, as you've noticed, affects both rows and columns, but I'll only talk about width since height handling is analogous.

Parts of an array or range not iterated over by a loop, especially ones at the end, is a typical symptom that the loop's condition and/or increment do not cover the entire array/range and need adjustment. In your case, to scan the entire image width, you'd need `frameWidth - roiw` to be an exact number of `StepRow`s, i.e. `(frameWidth - roiw) % StepRow == 0`. I strongly suspect that's not true in your case.

For example, if your image is 14 pixels wide, and your region of interest width is 8, in which case your step [would be 4 pixels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36568240/sliding-window-with-roi-c#comment60736480_36568240) (I assume you meant `roiw * 0.5`), then this would happen:
[image: incorrect step iteration]

Iteration #3 would fail the `rowindex <= frameWidth - roiw` test and exit the loop without scanning the last 2 pixels.

I see three options, each with its disadvantages:

*Disclaimer: All code below is not tested and may contain typos and logical errors. Please test and adjust accordingly.*

1. Change the offset of the last region so it fits the end of the image. In this case, the last `rowindex` increment would not be `StepRow` but the number of pixels between the end of your last scanning region and the end of the image. The drawback is that the last two regions may overlap more than those before them - in our case, region 1 would cover pixels 0:7, region 2 - 4:11 and region 3 - 6:13.

   To do this, you can modify your loop increment to check if this is the last iteration (please think of how to write it prettier, I just used the ternary operator to make the change smaller):

   ```
   for (int rowindex = 0;
        /* Note that a region of (roiw) pixels ending at (frameWidth - 1) should start
           at (frameWidth - roiw), so the <= operator should be correct. To verify that,
           check the single-region case where rowindex == 0 and frameWidth == roiw */
        rowindex <= frameWidth - roiw;
        rowindex += ((rowindex + roiw + StepRow <= frameWidth) ?
                    StepRow :
                    (frameWidth - (rowindex + roiw))))
   ```
2. Clamp the size of the last region to the end of the image. The drawback would be that your last region is smaller than those before it - in our case, regions 1 and 2 would have a size of 8, while region 3 would be 6 pixels.

   To do this, you can put a check when constructing the `cvRect` to see if it needs to be smaller. You should also change your loop condition somehow, so that you actually enter it in this case:

   ```
   /* (StepRow - 1) should make sure that enter the loop is entered when the
      last unscanned region has a width between 1 and stepRow, inclusive */
   for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex <= frameWidth - roiw + (StepRow - 1); rowindex += StepRow) 
   /* ... column loop ... */
     {
       if (rowindex > frameWidth - roiw)
       {
         roiw = frameWidth - rowindex;
       }
       searchRect = cvRect(rowindex, colindex, roiw, roih)
   ```
3. Use a varying step so that your regions are of equal width and overlap as equally as possible. In our case, the three regions would overlap equally, being at pixels 0:7, 3:11 and 6:14, but obviously that won't be true in most cases.

   To do that, you can calculate how many iterations you expect to do with your current step, and then divide by that number the difference between your frame and ROI width, which would give you your fractional step. Since pixel offset is an integer, to construct the `cvRect`, you'd need an integer value. I suggest keeping and incrementing the `rowindex` and step as fractions and converting to int just before use in the `cvRect` constructor - in this way, your index will move as evenly as possible.

   Note that I've used an epsilon value to (hopefully) avoid rounding errors in float-to-int conversion when the float value is very close to an int. See [this blog post and comments](http://fusharblog.com/add-epsilon-before-casting-double-to-integer/) for an example and an explanation of the technique. However, keep in mind that the code is not tested and there may still be rounding errors, especially if your int values are big!

   ```
   /* To see how these calculations work out, experiment with
      roiw == 8, StepRow == 4 and frameWidth == 14, 15, 16, 17 */
   /* N.B.: Does not cover the case when frameWidth < roiw! */
   int stepRowCount = (frameWidth - roiw + (StepRow - 1)) / StepRow + 1;
   float step = ((float)(frameWidth - roiw)) / (stepRowCount - 1);
   float eps = 0.005;

   for (float rowindex = 0.0; (int)(rowindex + eps) <= frameWidth - roiw; rowindex += StepRow) 
   /* ... column loop ... */
     {    searchRect = cvRect((int)(rowindex + eps), colindex, roiw, roih);
   ```

P.S.: Shouldn't your index that iterates the image width be called **colindex** and vice versa, since in an 1920x1080 image you have 1920 columns and 1080 rows (hence terms like *1080p*)?

Comment: First of all Answer to PS: yes it is vice a verse I guess while ı was wirting here I confused with matlab.

Comment: I am going to try and understand the logic behind your answer Thanks for your help sir! +1

Comment: If you have problems with any part, leave a comment and I'll try to clarify it.

Comment: when I use this approach you suggested I am not able to get out of the loop :

Comment: for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex <= lBPIIImage2.rows - roih; rowindex += ((lBPIIImage2.rows + roih + steprow <= lBPIIImage2.rows) ? steprow : (lBPIIImage2.rows - (rowindex + roih))))
 {

  for (int colindex = 0; colindex <= lBPIIImage2.cols - roiw; colindex += stepcol)

Comment: In your ternary operator, `(lBPIIImage2.rows + roih + steprow <= lBPIIImage2.rows)` is only true if `roih` and `steprow` are zero. In my code it is `(rowindex + roiw + StepRow <= frameWidth)`, which would be `(rowindex + roih + steprow <= lBPIIImage2.rows)` with your new names.

Comment: I made the neccsary changes which ar `for (int rowindex = 0; rowindex <= lBPIIImage2.rows - roih; rowindex += ((rowindex + roih + steprow <= lBPIIImage2.rows) ? steprow : (lBPIIImage2.rows - (rowindex + roih))))
    { 
  
  for (int colindex = 0; colindex <= lBPIIImage2.cols - roiw; colindex += ((colindex + roiw + stepcol <= lBPIIImage2.cols) ? stepcol : (lBPIIImage2.cols - (colindex + roiw))))

    {`

Comment: But ı am able to scan colmuns but cant move ın rows @mcmlxxxvi

Comment: I don't see anything wrong in these loops, so I suspect the problem is somewhere else, perhaps the cvRect constructor? Put your new relevant code in your question as suggested [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/39264/193877) so we can take another look.